# How do I HTML-/ URL-Encode a std::wstring containing Unicode characters?

Tags: c++, html, url, unicode, utf-8

I have another question yet. If I had a std::wstring looking like this:

> ドイツ語で検索していてこちらのサイトにたどり着きました。

How could I possibly get it to be URL-Encoded (*%nn*, *n* = 0-9, a-f) to:

> %E3%83%89%E3%82%A4%E3%83%84%E8%AA%9E%E3%81%A7%E6%A4%9C%E7%B4%A2%E3%81%97%E3%81%A6%E3%81%84%E3%81%A6%E3%81%93%E3%81%A1%E3%82%89%E3%81%AE%E3%82%B5%E3%82%A4%E3%83%88%E3%81%AB%E3%81%9F%E3%81%A9%E3%82%8A%E7%9D%80%E3%81%8D%E3%81%BE%E3%81%97%E3%81%9F%E3%80%82

... and also HTML-Encoded (*&#nnn*(*nn*);, *n* = 0-9(?)) to:

> ドイツ語で検索していてこちらのサイトにたどり着きました。

Please help me as I am totally lost right now and don't even know where to start. By the way, performance isn't much important to me right now.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Do you need a library or you want to code it yourself? Check [this](http://www.codeguru.com/cpp/cpp/cpp_mfc/article.php/c4029) article with a sample.

Comment: Are you bound to a specific operating system or should the program be platform-independent? The encoding used by `std::wstring` varies between operating systems.

Comment: Kirill: Oh, I don't care. I might try to do it myself instead of using a possibly bloated library :/
 
Philipp: I don't need it to be platform-independent. It's okay if it works on WIN32 only.

Answer (score 4):

Here is an example which shows two methods, one based on the Qt library and one based on the ICU library. Both should be fairly platform-independent:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <stdexcept>

#include <boost/scoped_array.hpp>

#include <QtCore/QString>
#include <QtCore/QUrl>
#include <QtCore/QVector>

#include <unicode/utypes.h>
#include <unicode/ustring.h>
#include <unicode/unistr.h>
#include <unicode/schriter.h>

void encodeQt() {
  const QString str = QString::fromWCharArray(L"ドイツ語で検索していてこちらのサイトにたどり着きました。");
  const QUrl url = str;
  std::cout << "URL encoded: " << url.toEncoded().constData() << std::endl;
  typedef QVector<uint> CodePointVector;
  const CodePointVector codePoints = str.toUcs4();
  std::stringstream htmlEncoded;
  for (CodePointVector::const_iterator it = codePoints.constBegin(); it != codePoints.constEnd(); ++it) {
    htmlEncoded << "&#" << *it << ';';
  }
  std::cout << "HTML encoded: " << htmlEncoded.str() << std::endl;
}

void encodeICU() {
  const std::wstring cppString = L"ドイツ語で検索していてこちらのサイトにたどり着きました。";
  int bufSize = cppString.length() * 2;
  boost::scoped_array<UChar> strBuffer(new UChar[bufSize]);
  int size = 0;
  UErrorCode error = U_ZERO_ERROR;
  u_strFromWCS(strBuffer.get(), bufSize, &size, cppString.data(), cppString.length(), &error);
  if (error) return;
  const UnicodeString str(strBuffer.get(), size);
  bufSize = str.length() * 4;
  boost::scoped_array<char> buffer(new char[bufSize]);
  u_strToUTF8(buffer.get(), bufSize, &size, str.getBuffer(), str.length(), &error);
  if (error) return;
  const std::string urlUtf8(buffer.get(), size);
  std::stringstream urlEncoded;
  urlEncoded << std::hex << std::setfill('0');
  for (std::string::const_iterator it = urlUtf8.begin(); it != urlUtf8.end(); ++it) {
    urlEncoded << '%' << std::setw(2) << static_cast<unsigned int>(static_cast<unsigned char>(*it));
  }
  std::cout << "URL encoded: " << urlEncoded.str() << std::endl;
  std::stringstream htmlEncoded;
  StringCharacterIterator it = str;
  while (it.hasNext()) {
    const UChar32 pt = it.next32PostInc();
    htmlEncoded << "&#" << pt << ';';
  }
  std::cout << "HTML encoded: " << htmlEncoded.str() << std::endl;
}


int main() {
  encodeQt();
  encodeICU();
}
```

Comment: Don't get me wrong! I appreciate your informative contribution and your time! But this looks way too bloated for my needs... :/

Answer (score 1):

You see, before you can convert a char to a URL escape sequence, you have to convert your wstring* into ISO-Latin charset which is what is used for URLs.  [ICU](http://site.icu-project.org/) could be a good place to start, where you can pass your wstring to it and get a ISO-Lantin sequence.  Then, simply iterate through the resulting chars and convert them to the escape senquence:

```
std::stringstream URL;
URL << std::hex;
for(auto it = myWString.begin(); it != myWString.end(); ++it)
   URL << '%' << std::setfill('0') << std::setw(2) << (int)*it;
```

Take a look [here](http://cplusplus.com/reference/iostream/manipulators/) for more info in how to format the string.

* I'm assuming that your wstring is a UTF-16, which usually is the case, although you didn't specify

[This](http://www.blooberry.com/indexdot/html/topics/urlencoding.htm) might help also.

Comment: Thanks for your time, but the example doesn't work well together with Unicode for me (results look like %n, %nn and even %nnn as well as %nnnn for some characters) :(

Comment: @Oliver sry, forgot about the width and fill guys.  I've included in the code above.  And like I said, you need to convert to ISO-Latin with ICU *before* using the sstream.

Comment: You cannot convert Chinese characters to a Latin encoding. Using UTF-8 is the common choice.

Comment: @Phillip Sure, it is most likely a mistake or wrongly documented, but URLs by default use ISO-Lantin (which is a subset of UTF-8) instead of UTF-8.  However, ignoring that and just using UTF-8 might still be safe.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a version that converts from UTF-16 (wchar) to hex-encoded UTF-8 using the Win32-specific WideCharToMultiByte() function.

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <windows.h>


std::string wstring_to_utf8_hex(const std::wstring &input)
{
  std::string output;
  int cbNeeded = WideCharToMultiByte(CP_UTF8, 0, input.c_str(), -1, NULL, 0, NULL, NULL);
  if (cbNeeded > 0) {
    char *utf8 = new char[cbNeeded];
    if (WideCharToMultiByte(CP_UTF8, 0, input.c_str(), -1, utf8, cbNeeded, NULL, NULL) != 0) {
      for (char *p = utf8; *p; *p++) {
        char onehex[5];
        _snprintf(onehex, sizeof(onehex), "%%%02.2X", (unsigned char)*p);
        output.append(onehex);
      }
    }
    delete[] utf8;
  }
  return output;
}


int main(int, char*[])
{
  std::wstring ja = L"ドイツ語で検索していてこちらのサイトにたどり着きました。";
  std::cout << "result=" << wstring_to_utf8_hex(ja) << std::endl;
  return 0;
}
```

To go the other way, you'll need to use some parsing to decode the hex values into a UTF-8 buffer, and then call the complimentary MultiByteToWideChar() to get it back into a wchar array.

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <windows.h>

std::string unhexlify(const std::string &input)
{
  std::string output;
  for (const char *p = input.c_str(); *p; ) {
    if (p[0] == '%' && isxdigit(p[1]) && isxdigit(p[2])) {
      int ch = (isdigit(p[1]) ? p[1] - '0' : toupper(p[1]) - 'A' + 10) * 16 + 
               (isdigit(p[2]) ? p[2] - '0' : toupper(p[2]) - 'A' + 10);
      output.push_back((char)ch);
      p += 3;
    } else if (p[0] == '%' && p[1] == '#' && isdigit(p[2])) {
      int ch = atoi(p + 2);
      output.push_back((char)ch);
      p += 2;
      while (*p && isdigit(*p)) p++;
      if (*p == ';') p++;
    } else {
      output.push_back(*p++);
    }
  }
  return output;
}


std::wstring utf8_hex_to_wstring(const std::string &input)
{
  std::wstring output;
  std::string utf8 = unhexlify(input);
  int cchNeeded = MultiByteToWideChar(CP_UTF8, 0, utf8.c_str(), -1, NULL, 0);
  if (cchNeeded > 0) {
    wchar_t *widebuf = new wchar_t[cchNeeded];
    if (MultiByteToWideChar(CP_UTF8, 0, utf8.c_str(), -1, widebuf, cchNeeded) != 0) {
      output = widebuf;
    }
    delete[] widebuf;
  }
  return output;
}

int main(int, char*[])
{
  std::wstring ja = L"ドイツ語で検索していてこちらのサイトにたどり着きました。";
  std::string hex = "%E3%83%89%E3%82%A4%E3%83%84%E8%AA%9E%E3%81%A7%E6%A4%9C%E7%B4%A2%E3%81%97%E3%81%A6%E3%81%84%E3%81%A6%E3%81%93%E3%81%A1%E3%82%89%E3%81%AE%E3%82%B5%E3%82%A4%E3%83%88%E3%81%AB%E3%81%9F%E3%81%A9%E3%82%8A%E7%9D%80%E3%81%8D%E3%81%BE%E3%81%97%E3%81%9F%E3%80%82";
  std::wstring newja = utf8_hex_to_wstring(hex);
  std::cout << "match?=" << (newja == ja ? "yes" : "no") << std::endl;
  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First, convert to UTF-8.
Then, normal URL/HTML encode would do the right thing.

Answer (score 0):

I find in `C#` it's simple, so I use `C++\CLI` as wrapper, wrap C# code:

```
string encodedStr = System.Web.HttpUtility.UrlEncode(inputstr);`
```

in `C++\CLI` make a method as `__declspec(dllexport)` so in C++ can call it, the `C++\CLI` syntax is:

```
String^ encodedStr  = System::Web::HttpUtility::UrlEncode(inputStr);`.
```

this is a tutorial about how to call `C++\CLI` from `C++`: [How to call a C# library from Native C++ (using C++\CLI and IJW)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13293888/how-to-call-a-c-sharp-library-from-native-c-using-c-cli-and-ijw)