# Encoding unicode characters in URL using Win32

Tags: c++, winapi, url, unicode, character-encoding

I am developing a Windows based application in which I need to pass unicode characters as part of the URL. I read that I need to percent encode them inorder to do so. According to my understanding windows programs are use `UCS-2` encoding so I need to convert the characters to first to `UTF-8` and then percent encode them. I tried using `MultiByteToWideChar` along with `UrlEscape` without much success. Can anybody tell me what is the correct way to do this?

Comment: Maybe redundant to http://stackoverflow.com/q/3300025/1758762

Comment: It *looks* like you're trying at least toward right direction. Did you consider using the wininet library (specifically, [InternetCanonicaliizeUrl()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa384342(v=vs.85).aspx))? Or is that off the table?

Comment: To convert from UCS-2 (UTF-16, actually) to UTF-8, you'll need `WideCharToMultiByte`.

Comment: You also need to ensure the receiving code expects URL encoded UTF-8. HTTP doesn't care how it's encoded, as long as it's valid data. It can be base64 encoded morse if you wish as long as both ends agree :)